# Speed up complex-number parsing dictionary creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I made a code that generates a string of text base 3, similar to the way that numbers are written in base 3, but the base are complex numbers

For example:

```
"0"=(0+0*i)
"1"=(1+0*i)
"A"=(1/2+0.866*i)
"10A"=(1+0*i)*2^2 + (0+0*i)*2^1 + (1/2+0.866*i)*2^0
```

The code works, but it is ultra slow.

The slow part is the creation of a dictionary, whose purpose is to get the numerical value of each string:

```
#Generate dictionary to convert string to the complex coordinates
NumDict = {} 
for Num in AllStringsBase3:
    NumDict[Num]=CoordinatesOfString(Num)
```

Can it be made faster?
I do not necessarily need a dictionary. Only a fast way to get the value of each string, for manipulation purposes

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import cmath as cm

#Calculates coordinates of string
#The string is interpreted similar to a binary number, where each position is weigted by a power of 2
#
#Answer=char1Value*2**0 + char2Value*2**1 + ... + charnValue*2**n
#Returns complex number
def CoordinatesOfString(ArrayNum):
    Answer=complex(0,0)
    for i in np.arange(len(ArrayNum)):
        Answer=Answer+WeightOfBase[ArrayNum[i]]*2**i
    return Answer


#This code generates a base 3 list of strings, to represent 2D points matching Serpinsky triangle
StringLength=10


UpperVertex = cm.rect(1, cm.pi/3)#Complex coordinates of upper vertex of equilateral triangle = 1.e^(i.pi/3)
Base = ["0", "1", "A"] #text base 
Weights = [complex(0,0), complex(1,0), UpperVertex]#numerical values of the text base

WeightOfBase={} #Dictionary key=Base Value=Weigth
for i in np.arange(len(Base)):
    WeightOfBase[Base[i]]=Weights[i]

#generate all combinations of Base chars
AllStringsBase3 = list(itertools.product(Base, repeat=StringLength))
#print(AllStringsBase3)

#Generate dictionary to convert string to the complex coordinates
NumDict = {} 
for Num in AllStringsBase3:
    NumDict[Num]=CoordinatesOfString(Num)

#print(NumDict)




import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x, y = zip(*[(z.real, z.imag) for z in NumDict.values()]) 
plt.scatter(x, y, label="star", marker=".", color="green", s=1)
plt.xlabel('real axis')
plt.ylabel('imaginary axis')
plt.title('Sierpinski')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm not quite following your notation. What is ``1.2^2 + 0.2^1 + (1/2+0.866.i).2^0`` supposed to be? Is the ``.`` multiplication? Why do you use numpy for simples ranges, instead of the builtins? There should be no advantage (likely a disadvantage instead) to using numpy.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, is multipication. I fixed the text. I always use numpy and pandas, but would use other thing if faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use Python's builtin number parsing to speed up `CoordinatesOfString`, which is the bottleneck. The key is that each number can be split into a separate number for each digit, which can be individually translated and merged via addition.

For example, the number `110A0A1` can be decomposed to the sum of

- the 0-digits `0000000` or `0`,
- the 1-digits `1100001` or `1100001`,
- the A-digits `000A0A0` or `A * 0001010`.

We can use `str.replace` to transform the initial literal to the 1-digit and A-digit literals. Using `int(..., 2)` allows to parse these as binary literals.

```py
def parse(literal: str):  # CoordinatesOfString
    ones = literal.replace('A', '0')                     # 1100001
    coms = literal.replace('1', '0').replace('A', '1')   # 0001010
    return int(ones, 2) + (0.5 + 0.866j) * int(coms, 2)  # 0b1100001 + A * 0b0001010
```

This function directly parses literals, e.g. `parse("10A")` evaluates to `(4.5+0.866j)`. In order to parse the list-of-digits, use `NumDict[Num]=parse(''.join(Num))`.

The tested speedup is x1.2 for literals of length 2, x2 for literals of length 4, x4 for literals of length 10, and x5 for literals of length 15.

Comment: looks promising, more vectorizable and out the box. I'm checking the performance.